# What is the difference between "tail -f" and "tail -F"?

Tags: tail

I never used `tail -F` command instead always used `tail -f` however someone told me that `-F` is better without much explanation.

I looked up man page for tail command.

```
-f output appended data as the file grows;

-F Same as --follow=name --retry

--retry Keep trying to open a file even when it is or becomes inaccessible
```

It is easy to understand what lower `-f` does but I do not follow what upper case `-F` is trying to do. I'd appreciate someone can explain to me the differences.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

You describe the GNU `tail` utility.  The difference between these two flags is that if I open a file, a log file for example, like this:

```
$ tail -f /var/log/messages
```

... and if the log rotation facility on my machine decides to rotate that log file while I'm watching messages being written to it ("rotate" means delete or move to another location etc.), the output that I see will just stop.

If I open the file with `tail` like this:

```
$ tail -F /var/log/messages
```

... and again, the file is rotated, the output would continue to flow in my console because `tail` would reopen the file as soon as it became available again, i.e. when the program(s) writing to the log started writing to the *new* `/var/log/messages`.

On the free BSD systems, there is no `-F` option, but `tail -f` will behave like `tail -F` does on GNU systems, with the difference that you get the message

```
tail: file has been replaced, reopening.
```

in the output when the file you're monitoring disappears and reappears.

---

**YOU CAN TEST THIS**

In one shell session, do

```
$ cat >myfile
```

That will now wait for you to type stuff.  Just go ahead and type some gibberish, a few lines. It will all be saved into the file `myfile`.

In *another* shell session (maybe in another terminal, *without interrupting the `cat`*):

```
$ tail -f myfile
```

This will show the (end of the) contents of `myfile` in the console.  If you go back to the first shell session and type something more, that output will immediately be shown by `tail` in the second shell session.

Now quit `cat` by pressing <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd>, and *remove* the `myfile` file:

```
$ rm myfile
```

Then run the cat again:

```
$ cat >myfile
```

... and type something, a few lines.

With GNU `tail`, these lines will *not* show up in the second shell session (where `tail -f` is still running).

*Repeat the exercise with `tail -F` and observe the difference.*

Comment: Oh..I see. I have a system log file such as foo.log then I see sometimes foo_06242016.log along with foo.log. So I run tail -f foo.log, it will point to foo_06242016.log?

Comment: @DaeYoung No, not quite. If you run `tail -f foo.log` and your system moves `foo.log` to e.g. `foo.log.0.gz` the output you see would just stop. If you use `-F` on the other hand, you would see the contents of *the new* `foo.log` without any break in-between.

Answer (score 17):

Simplified, when you open a file, you will get the inode that contains some metadata of where exactly the file is located on your disk. Tail will then listen for changes to that file.

If you remove the file, and create a new one with the same name the filename will be the same but it's a different inode (and probably stored on a different place on your disk). `tail -f` fill not retry and load the new inode, `tail -F` will detect this.

The same effect will happen if you rename/move a file. If you for example follows `/var/log/messages` and logrotate rotates the log to `/var/log/messages.1`. tail with `-f` will still listen to the old inode that points to `messages.1`. tail with `-F` will realize this and read the new inode.