# How can I view the file output of a program in a text file as it's being populated?

Tags: files, output

Say I've got a text file `file.txt` and program `program.rb`. `program.rb` writes stuff to `file.txt` as `program.rb` finds it. How can I view the population of the text file from the terminal?

Comment: `tail -f file.txt` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is commonly done with `tail -f`:

```
$ tail -f file.txt
```

The `tail` utility outputs the *tail* of a file or stream, i.e. the last part of it (the 10 last lines by default).  With the `-f` flag, it will not exit once it has arrived at the end, but continue polling the file or stream for new data and output it whenever it arrives.

This is commonly done to manually monitor log files, or, as in your case, to view the partial result of a running program.

See also question [291932](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/291932/what-is-the-difference-between-tail-f-and-tail-f) to learn the difference between `tail -f` and `tail -F`.

Comment: Another possibility is to view the file with `less` and press Shift + F.